# graphql-upload multiple file transfer with apollo-server-express

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

My use Apollo-server, expressjs;

while there is no problem with small file transfers,

I can't get files after the 1st in nodejs in large files

server.js:

```
app.use('/graphql',graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 100000000, maxFiles: 10 }))
```

my-resolver:

```
multiUpload: async (obj, { files },{ Models }) => {

  const results = await (files.map(async val=>await val.file));

})
```

small files resolvers req:
a.txt: 253 bayt
b.txt: 335 bayt

```
[
 Promise {
  {
   filename: 'a.txt',
   mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
   encoding: '7bit',
   createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
  }
 },
 Promise {
  {
   filename: 'b.txt',
   mimetype: 'text/plain',
   encoding: '7bit',
   createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
  }
 }
]
```

big files resolvers req:
a.jpeg: 3.9 Mb
b.jpeg: 4 Mb

```
Promise {
 {
  filename: 'a.jpg',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
 }
},
Promise { undefined }
]
```

May I know why?

thank you for helping

Comment: ... promise.all ?

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same
      let a=Promise.all(  files.map ((async val=>{
       await new (async (resolve,reject)=>{
          resolve(val.file)
        })
        
      })))
      console.log(a); // Promise { <pending> }

      
      // -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
      eve=( (a,i)=>{
        return  files.map ((val=>val.file))
      });
      console.log( promisify(eve)());// Promise { <pending> }
      // -*-*-*-*-*-*
      only the right promise
        setTimeout( () => {
         const a=files.map ((val=>val.file))
         console.log(a);
        }, 200);